# How to define byte[] and LocalDateTime in avro schema?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

Im new to Avro schema. I try to publish/consumer my java objects using kafka.
I have java bean classes, which contains fields with LocalDateTime and byte[] . How can i define both in avro schema primitive types? What is the best primitive type i can use for LocalDateTime?

```
private LocalDateTime timestamp; 
private byte[] content;
```

I defined something like this; but getting

```
 {
            "name": "content", "type": "bytes"
         },
```

Class cast exception[1]

> [1] Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer   at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeBytes(GenericDatumWriter.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:58)

Comment: What about Avro's "bytes" primitive for `byte[]`? http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#schema_primitive

Comment: Can Avro bytes be used to store byte[] without losing info? I tried base64 encoding and used avro string datatype which works, wondering if it will work without encoding.  I am trying to store a png image inside one of avro's field. Will be great if there is an example that shows how to do.

Comment: Got it. Have used ByteBuffer to store byte[] in avro. ByteBuffer.wrap will help you do the conversion from byte[] to ByteBuffer. Not sure of the encoding part though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the byte[] you can use the bytes primitive as miguno said. For the LocalDateTime object you can store it as a long primitive, by converting it to milliseconds. Avro also supports Logical Types that you can use to directly deserialize into something that is not part of the primitive types. See [here](https://github.com/mtth/avsc/wiki/Advanced-usage#logical-types) for more details and an example similar to what you want to achieve.